# Text alignment of command output

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have created a new command where the functionality works as expected, but the output is a Little unexpected. As you can see, the "Else" text is not aligned with the "Kaldenavn" text. How can it be and how can I fix it?

The method I have created is the one called: textlabel

[image]

Minimum working code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}           % Til tabeller der tilpaser sig i bredden
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}r}

\usepackage{xifthen}            % Used to test if an argument is empty
\usepackage{datetime}           % Used to format dates
\newdateformat{timeLineDate}{\THEDAY.~\shortmonthname~\THEYEAR}
\newdateformat{monthYearDate}{\monthname[\THEMONTH]~\THEYEAR}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\textlabel}[2]{%
  \edef\@currentlabel{#1}% Set target label
  \phantomsection% Correct hyper reference link
  #1\label{#2}% Print and store label
}
\makeatother

%Arguments: 
%   1)  MANDATORY    - Reference to the current full name
%   2)  MANDATORY    - Full birth name
%   3)  OPTIONAL     - Called name
%   4)  OPTIONAL     - Birth date in the format of dd. mmm. yyyy
%   5)  OPTIONAL     - Death date in the format of dd. mmm. yyyy
%   6)  MANDATORY   - Uniqueue Reference number
\newcommand{\createPerson}[6]
{
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXRc}%
            Navn:   &   \nameref{#1}  &   \ifNoArgumentElse{#4}{&}{#4 &   $\star$}\\%
            \ifNoArgumentElse{#2}{Kaldenavn:    &   \textlabel{#3}{sth:text}}{Fødenavn:   &   #2} &   \ifNoArgumentElse{#5}{&}{#5 & \cross}%
            \ifNoArgumentElse{#2}{\\&& #6 & $\Re$}{\\Kaldenavn: & \textlabel{#3}{abc:#3} & #6 & $\Re$}%
        \end{tabularx}%
}

%Arguments
%   1) The argument to test
%   2) If empty then do this
%   3) If not empty then do this
\newcommand{\ifNoArgumentElse}[3]{
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{#2}{#3}%
}

\newcommand{\cross}[1][1pt]{\ooalign{%
  \rule[1ex]{1ex}{#1}\cr% Horizontal bar
  \hss\rule{#1}{.7em}\hss\cr}% Vertical bar
}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Else Jensen}
\label{person1}

\createPerson
    {person1}
    {Else Nielsen}
    {Else}
    {11. sep. 2010}
    {13. nov. 2013}
    {222}

\ref{abc:Else} was a good student.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Quite complicated setup -- perhaps you should use `\NewDocumentCommand` and it's features for `\createperson`?

Comment: I am alway open to better solutions :) How would you do that?

Comment: The mere purpose of `\ifNoArgumentElse` is to check if the argument is there or empty, is that correct?

Comment: I suspect `\textlabel` is the cause

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes, that is correct.

Comment: You should add a pair of braces in the definition of `\cross`, around the whole `\ooalign{...}`: `\newcommand{\cross}[1][1pt]{{\ooalign{...}}}`. Otherwise using `\cross` at the top level of a document will have quite unexpected consequences.

Comment: This 6-argument - macro is quite error-prone. A key-value -syntax might be a better approach!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have tried to create a new command as you suggested. However, I am having a bit of trouble doing it, so I have created a new question. Hope you will help :) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274047/xparse-doesnt-recognize-some-of-my-variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting the text before `\phantomsection` seems to work:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\textlabel}[2]{%
  \edef\@currentlabel{#1}% Set target label
   #1\phantomsection\label{#2}% Print and store label
}
\makeatother
```

The hyperlink appears to work as well (removal of `\phatomsection` would reference the top of the page).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked very well :) will you maybe elaborate a bit on how to use the newDocumentCommand you mentioned in the comment before?

Comment: @FireFly3000: I've suggested that ;-) I detected the `\phantomsection` culprit as well, but Guho was faster. Besides that, I recommend a better design as well, using a key-value syntax instead a 6-argument macro

Comment: Sorry, I actually believed that it was your answer.

Comment: @FireFly3000: Oh my :D :D :D