# XParse doesn't recognize some of my variables

Tags: macros, conditionals, xparse

Based on the comments from my last [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273891/text-alignment-of-command-output/273895?noredirect=1#comment658677_273895) have I tried to create a new command using `\NewDocumentCommand`. However, it wont recognize some of the optional arguments - they just get printed as is. Any idea why and how to solve it?

Minimum code sample:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}           % Til tabeller der tilpaser sig i bredden
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}r}

\usepackage{xifthen}            % Used to test if an argument is empty
\usepackage{datetime}           % Used to format dates
\newdateformat{timeLineDate}{\THEDAY.~\shortmonthname~\THEYEAR}
\newdateformat{monthYearDate}{\monthname[\THEMONTH]~\THEYEAR}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\textlabel}[2]{%
  \edef\@currentlabel{#1}% Set target label
  \phantomsection% Correct hyper reference link
  #1\label{#2}% Print and store label
}
\makeatother

\NewDocumentCommand\createPersonNew{omomd<>o}
{
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXRc}%
        Navn:   &   #2    & #4    & $\Re$\\

        \IfNoValueTF{#1#3}{}{&&\IfNoValueTF{#5}{\IfNoValueTF{#6}{}{#6 & \cross}}{#5 & $\star$ \IfNoValueTF{#6}{}{\\&& #6 & \cross}}}
        %...
    \end{tabularx}%
}

%Arguments
%   1) The argument to test
%   2) If empty then do this
%   3) If not empty then do this
\newcommand{\ifNoArgumentElse}[3]{
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{#2}{#3}%
}

\newcommand{\cross}[1][1pt]{\ooalign{%
  \rule[1ex]{1ex}{#1}\cr% Horizontal bar
  \hss\rule{#1}{.7em}\hss\cr}% Vertical bar
}

\newcommand{\printLongDate}[3]{%
    \ifNoArgumentElse{#1#2#3}{}{%
        \ifNoArgumentElse{#1}{%
            \ifNoArgumentElse{#2}{#3}{\monthYearDate\formatdate{1}{#2}{#3}}%
        }{\formatdate{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Else Jensen}
\label{person1}

\createPersonNew
    [else]
    {Else1940}
    [Else Jensen]
    {340}
    [\printLongDate{12}{01}{1963}]
    <\printLongDate{24}{09}{1979}>

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just seen it -- I'll take a look

Comment: You've accidentally called `..[ ... ]<...>`  but the specification is `omomd<>o` -- and `\IfNoValueTF{#1#3}` is wrong! -- I would suggest to use `\NewDocumentCommand` for `\printLongDate` too

Comment: I can't recommend this nested way at the moment

Comment: You can't use `\IfNoValueTF{#1#3}`, period.

Comment: The whole nesting is weird and cumbersome. I really suggest a clear `key-value` interface for this

Comment: Besides using the meaningless `\IfNoValueTF{#1#3}`, you're using the wrong order of the two final optional arguments at calling time. The one in brackets `[...]` should go *after* the one between `<` and `>`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Do you have any suggestions for a key-value interface to use?

Comment: @FireFly3000: Actually, that's a new question. But `xkeyval` and the `expl3` might help to achieve the goal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some errors were detected:

- The interface for arguments 5 and 6 were misused and swapped
- `\IfNoValueTF{#1#3} is wrong -- the`\IfNoValueTF` macro is meant for one optional argument only, not for a combination of them
- There must be newline characters between the arguments!

In addition, I 'improved' `\printLongDate` a little bit

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}           % Til tabeller der tilpaser sig i bredden
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}r}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xifthen}            % Used to test if an argument is empty
\usepackage{datetime}           % Used to format dates
\newdateformat{timeLineDate}{\THEDAY.~\shortmonthname~\THEYEAR}
\newdateformat{monthYearDate}{\monthname[\THEMONTH]~\THEYEAR}


\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\textlabel}[2]{%
  \edef\@currentlabel{#1}% Set target label
  \phantomsection% Correct hyper reference link
  #1\label{#2}% Print and store label
}

\makeatother


\NewDocumentCommand\createPersonNew{omomo+d<>}
{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXRc}%
    Navn:   &   #2    & #4    & $\Re$\\
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{}{&&\IfNoValueTF{#5}{\IfNoValueTF{#6}{}{#6 & \cross}}{#5 & $\star$ \IfNoValueTF{#6}{}{\\&& #6 & \cross}}}
    % ...
  \end{tabularx}%
}



%Arguments
%   1) The argument to test
%   2) If empty then do this
%   3) If not empty then do this
\newcommand{\ifNoArgumentElse}[3]{
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{#2}{#3}%
}

\newcommand{\cross}[1][1pt]{\ooalign{%
  \rule[1ex]{1ex}{#1}\cr% Horizontal bar
  \hss\rule{#1}{.7em}\hss\cr}% Vertical bar
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printLongDate}{od<>o}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{#3}{%
      \protect\monthYearDate\formatdate{1}{#2}{#3}
    }%
  }{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{#3}{%
      \protect\formatdate{#1}{#2}{#3}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Else Jensen}
\label{person1}

\createPersonNew[else]{Else1940}[Else Jensen]{340}[\printLongDate[12]<01>[1963]]<
\printLongDate[24]<09>[1979]>

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not sure whether the `\protect\monthYearDate` is necessary. Perhaps `\protect` can be deleted here